# How to assert that a method has not been called after an exception has been thrown?

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

I have a method which posts to an API and then does other business logic after the call within the method. If something goes wrong for whatever reason when posting to the API, the API returns an exception. I don't want to catch this exception as I don't want the code to continue on executing. So far in my unit test, I've mocked the API and wrote `when(APIService.postDetails(any())).thenThrow(Exception.class)` and to assert I've verified that a few of the methods have been called 0 times through the `verify` method in mockito.

When I try and run the test, the test fails.  I get a `java.lang.Exception` that's expected, but I was also expecting for the unit test to assert on the verify. Is it possible?

Test:

```
   @Test
   public void shouldCallPublishZeroTimes(){
      Account account = Account.builder()
              .street("ZBC123")
              .address("123456")
              .postcode("w19uu")
              .build();
      List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
      accountList.add(account);

      when(customerDB.getExistingClient(any())).thenThrow(Exception.class);

      client.createAccount();

      verify(eventPublisher, times(0)).publish(any());
   }
```

Comment: you mean to assert that after the exception is caught?

Comment: Can you post the code of test?

Comment: @Stultuske yes but in this case I am not catching the exception. My app is a Spring MVC app so I'm thinking by not catching the exception, the execution of the code would stop but the app would still be up and running ready to take REST calls.. right?

Comment: yes, but the moment that exception is thrown, your test is done and goes no further

Comment: Why can't you have two different tests, one test for the scenario when the exception is thrown and another for scenario when the exception is NOT thrown?

Answer (score 0):

In is the past I have done this:

```
@Test
public void shouldCallPublishZeroTimes(){
    Account account = Account.builder()
            .street("ZBC123")
            .address("123456")
            .postcode("w19uu")
            .build();
    List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
    accountList.add(account);

    when(customerDB.getExistingClient(any())).thenThrow(Exception.class);
    try {
        client.createAccount();
        fail();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        verify(eventPublisher, times(0)).publish(any());
    }
}
```